# И снова о запятой перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

И еще. Такое предложение: "А то, что сейчас, - это не ценности, это перевернутая мораль". Правильно ли тут стоит запятая перед тире?

Comment: Простите, не имею возможности продолжать в комментариях.

@Ларf, а вот вам пример поглощения тире (чем) запятой (чего):
В. Ф. Панова. Конспект романа (1965) ...   *Другой раз ― это было в конце учебного года, в ветреный и солнечный майский день ― ребята сидели в скверике на скамейке, возле загородки с песком, и разговаривали о своих делах.*  

"в ветреный и солнечный майский день" - явно обособляемое уточнение, но пред тире закрывающая запятая пропадает. 

Я понимаю, что этот случай отличается от исходного, но чем именно - и где это написано?

Comment: В Вашем последнем примере вставная конструкция выделяется тире, уточнение вовсе не обязательно. А если захочется - вполне можно ее поставить перед второй тире.
Разве у Лопатина в "Правилах" не явно прописано? П.155 и далее: "Сочетание знаков препинания и последовательность их расположения". Например, п. 156 про тире и запятую, п. 157 про двоеточие и запятую.

Comment: "У Лопатина в Правилах"? Это где? Тут? http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=472 В 155 нет решительно ничего по вопросу. А 156 как раз и говорит о том, что запятая поглощается при встрече с двоеточием или точкой запятой. И я позволю себе в третий раз сформулировать вопрос: в каких случаях запятая поглощается тире (подобно тому, как она "поглощается" запятой) - и где это написано.

Comment: Простите, но обязательно оно или нет - вопрос абстрактный. Оно есть. И оно "обособлено" запятой спереди: "это было в конце учебного года, в ветреный и солнечный майский день". А вторая запятая, закрывающая, запятая поглощена тире. По-другому я трактовать эту конструкцию не могу. 

Впрочем, даже если вы дадите другое толкование для данного примера (в чем я сомневаюсь), примеров подобного я могу найти достаточно.

*Вам кажется, что заржавела металлическая ось ручки терморегулятора[,] ― обратитесь к врачу по месту жительства.* - закрывающая запятая поглощена тире.

Comment: Мы как будто разные книги читаем:§ 156. При сочетании в тексте тире и запятой вначале ставится запятая (запятая закрывает впереди стоящую конструкцию), затем тире. В Вашем последнем примере я бы запятую поставила.  
И вообще, может, мы просто о разном говорим?  Мне  кажется, я все больше о правилах (профессия сказывается), а Вы  - о фактических случаях употребления, а авторы, как известно, иногда претендуют на свою, авторскую пунктуацию.

Comment: Я говорю: 
1. О правилах и только о них.   
2. О правилах поглощения тире запятой.  
3. О том, что эти правила нигде в полном виде не сформулировны. 
4. О том, что Вашс тези "чем открыли - тем и закрывайте" никак не может претендовать на универсальный и нуждается как минимум во многих существенных оговорках.  
Все последние примеры относились именно к последнему пункту. 
Авторская пункутцация здесь ни при чем: 1) количество примеров "поглощения" явно превышает разумный масксимум для такого объяснения, 2) частично эти правила описаны, но именно - частично.
Я открою новую тему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно. Запятой Вы закрываете придаточное предложение (что сейчас), а тире ставится перед "это" в данном случае

Answer (score 0):

Да. Тире получается между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Answer (score 0):

Вы, как я понимаю, сомневаетесь не в тире, а в запятой. 
Я в ней тоже сомневаюсь, ибо, сколько не бился, четкого ответа на то, в каких случаях тире "съедает" запятую и где это прописано, я не нашел.
По факту обычно эту запятую не опускают, запятая здесь как бы более весомый знак, а тире, как было сказано, прямого отношения к синтаксису не имеет и ставится перед "это" как присоединительный знак (присоединятет сказуемое к подлежащему).

Comment: А что в ней сомневаться-то - придаточное предложение надо закрыть!

Comment: Вот тире (чем) и закройте.  
Ларf, о своих сомнениях по этому поводу я говорил неоднократно, ответа не получил. Не стоит ещё и здесь это разводить.

Во всяком случае безапелляционные указивки "нельзя, но надо" на меня не действуют.

Comment: Чем открыли (запятой), тем и закрывать нужно. Каждый знак свою функцию выполняет. По своей причине ставится. Искренне не понимаю Ваших сомнений.И грубости, простите, тоже.

Comment: Ох, видит Бог, не хотел я...  
Перед каим этих знаков Вы можете представить запятую:
точка, вопросительный знак, воскличательный знак, закрывающая скобка, закрывающая кавычка, точка с запятой, многоточие, двоеточие?  
Если хоть один пример подобного приведете - я приму к сведенью Ваше мнение о необходимости "закрывать тем, чем отркрыли". 
Или давайте другую формулировку, с указанием чем тире лучше (или хуже) упомянутых знаков.

Comment: Ага... Поняла... Предложение в вопросе отличается от Ваших предполагаемых предложений тем, что  придаточное предложение находится в середине предложения. Поэтому и имела в виду именно этот тип предложения. И вообще термин "открыть - закрыть придаточное" мы употребляем именно для такой позиции.

Comment: Нет, видимо, всё-таки не поняли. Конец предложения - это точка или там восклицательный знак. Но с каких пор **концом** предложения стало, например, двоеточие? Почему на этот случай не рапространяется сентенция "чем открыли - тем и закройте"?

Comment: *"Меня зовут Аня, и я очень рада, что теперь моя работа напрямую связана с тем, что я люблю: с организацией праздников".*
Где закрывающая запятая после "люблю"? И в то же время:
*"Меня зовут Аня, и я очень рада, что теперь моя работа напрямую связана с тем, что я люблю, - с организацией праздников".*

Пример с Грамоты, так что сомнения в пунктуации, думаю, неуместны.
Повторяю вопрос. В чем разница между тире и двоеточием в плане "поглощения" запятой? И где это прописано в явном виде?

Comment: Мне кажется, когда-то мы уже об этом говорили, и ссылка была. Поищу еще раз. Чуть позже.